# Rationally graded singular cohomology

Tags: cohomology, orbifolds

In the paper "A new cohomology theory for orbifold" by Chen/Ruan, they define the *orbifold cohomology group* of an orbifold $X$ by

$H^d_{orb}(X)=\bigoplus_{(g) \in T} H^{d-2\iota_{(g)}}(X_{(g)})$

where $H^\ast(X_{(g)})$ is the singular cohomology of $X_{(g)}$ with real coefficients and $\iota(g)$ is a rational number.

Also, the *orbifold Dolbeault cohomology group* is defined by

$H^{p,q}_{orb}(X)=\bigoplus_{(g) \in T}H^{p-\iota_{(g)},q-\iota_{(g)}}(X_{(g)})$.

How are these cohomologies with rational coefficients defined?

EDIT: In Adem/Leida/Ruan's "Orbifolds and stringy topology" they similarly define the Chen-Ruan cohomology group for orbifold groupoid as

$H^d_{CR}=\bigoplus_{(g) \in T}H^d(X_{(g)})[-2\iota_{(g)}]=\bigoplus_{(g) \in T}H^{d-2\iota_{(g)}}(X_{(g)})$,

but I am also unfamiliar with the notation $H^d(X_{(g)})[-2\iota_{(g)}]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is my understanding that $H^d$ is taken to be trivial unless $d$ is an integer. Hence this is just notation for a degree shift by a rational number.

Similarly, in the other formula, the square bracket notation is also just a degree-shift.

Comment: In the [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0004129v3.pdf), p. 27 they calculate the numbers $h^{d}=1$ for the weighted projective space with $d$ rational.

Comment: There are two different cohomology theories going on. This (p. 27) is a calculation of the orbifold cohomology with $d$ rational.
Elsewhere, the orbifold cohomology is defined in terms of ordinary cohomology, and that is extended from integer gradings to rational gradings by taking it to be trivial for non-integer degrees.
So the theory they define has interesting behaviour in rational degrees, even though the theory it's defined in terms of doesn't.